# How to get the output of a color from a LinearSegmentedColormap object

Tags: python, matplotlib

python 3.9

I'm using matplot lib to create a color. I want to add that color to a unit test, but I'm not sure how to get the color out of the object.

```py
color1= LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    "COLOR1_CMAP",
    (
        _normalize_rgb(*_rgb.BLACK),
        _normalize_rgb(*_rgb.BLUE),
        _normalize_rgb(*_rgb.YELLOW),
        _normalize_rgb(*_rgb.RED),
        _normalize_rgb(*_rgb.WHITE),
    ),
    gamma=1.0,
)
```

How do I get the colors that were set from color1 w/out going to look at the source code?

I tried `camo.colors` but got the error message `AttributeError: 'LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'colors'`

Comment: You can use `[color1(i) for i in range(color1.N)]` to get a list of all the 256 colors.  The colors used for constructing the colormap don't seem to be accessible as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recover the initial colors from the `_segmentdata` *private* attribute of the `LinearSegmentedColormap` object. This attribute holds the RGBA values of each input color in a dictionary. [See here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e24008033972a5987fed55300bd9db5ea3cacd10/lib/matplotlib/colors.py#L1062)

The following snippet will return the input rgba colors used to create the colormap

```py
rgba_colors = np.array([channel[:, 1] for channel in color1._segmentdata.values()])
rgba_colors.T
```

**Important Note**: I do not recommend using a private attribute like so for anything serious.

Using your example:

```
expected_colors = np.array([
    [0., 0., 0., 1.],  # Black
    [0., 0., 1., 1.],  # Blue
    [1., 1., 0., 1.],  # Yellow
    [1., 0., 0., 1.],  # Red
    [1., 1., 1., 1.]   # White
])

rgba_colors = np.array([channel[:, 1] for channel in color1._segmentdata.values()])
retrieved_colors = rgba_colors.T

np.testing.assert_array_equal(expected_colors, retrieved_colors)
```

*(If you need rgb colors only : `retrieved_colors[: , :3]`)*